# Azure mobile service insert item with identity field

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to make an insert into my Azure Mobile Service table but it fails if i have a field in my class that is marked as identity in the database. If i then change so that i dont have it in my class then I´m  not able to get the field from the database. I need to be able to do both but at the moment i have to choose if i want to be able to insert or read.

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have the same problem in both Android and C#.

I have tried to delete the set; propperty in the class but then i can´t get the field from the database.

Comment: Need more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the basic table methods in Azure Mobile Services your underlying table must conform to the following rules:

- The table must be in the schema of your Mobile Service (the schema is
  the name of your Mobile Service)
- The table must have an identity column called ‘id’ and it must be all lower case letters

You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/05/24/using-an-existing-azure-sql-table-with-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I understood your problem (I hope so !).

The entities should look like this:

```
public class Foo: EntityData
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you try to add a new Foo with a reference to an existing category, all you have to do when creating the object is specifying the CategoryId and leave the Category member alone:

```
Foo f = new Foo() {
    CategoryId = a_correct_Category_Id,
    Name = "a name"
}
```

Otherwise, when doing something like this:

```
Foo f = new Foo() {
    Category = a_category_object,
    Name = "a name"
}
```

When Entity Framework will try to add a new Foo object, it will also try to add a new Category object. You get an error if it already exists in the database

Comment: Sorry but you didn´t get it. I found out that it is a problem in the Azure database wich they will have to fix.